# Using Lagrange equations for pulley systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string

1. Can I know how to solve pulley based problems using Lagrange Equations?
2. How can I use it for systems with many pulleys?
3. What is the basic idea behind it?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how you would go about setting up the Lagrangian. The basic idea is to use L = T  - V. Are you looking for an example? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics

Comment: This may be a good treatment on the subject. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node79.html

Comment: @Inquisitive  nice example, I had forgotten they were called Atwood machines